# Front jack point

Tags: nissan, sentra, jack, jack-stand

I have a 2002 Nissan Sentra and need to remove the front passenger wheel to remove the windshield washer reservoir. I have jack stands and a low profile hydraulic jack.
I want to know where I can precisely put the jack stand to lift the car without damaging anything.

[image: Passenger side view]

[image: Front view]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack here is safe, be sure to use jack stand also.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!! If I wanted to raise the front and place 2 jack stands, would the hump on my second photo work?

Comment: Better to place jack stands on the box frame behind the jack point.